# How to set private key pin using CERT_CONTEXT

Tags: c, cryptography, cryptoapi

I need to set Private Key Pin without CSP window.

I've got an `CERT_CONTEXT` structure and i call `CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey` with silent flag. Function fails with `NTE_SILENT_CONTEXT` error message. It means that pin was not specified or incorrect and the CSP window was blocked. I need to get private key provider to set pin via `CryptSetProvParam` function. 
How can I get provider only by `CERT_CONTEXT` structure?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use CryptSetProvParam with PP_KEYEXCHANGE_PIN (or PP_SIGNATURE_PIN). This flag is not supported by the default Microsoft crypto-service-provider (it is intended for use with smartcard-based CSPs).